# Handlebars get a certain value of a key inside an object

Tags: arrays, object, each, handlebars.js

So I have an array which holds objects and inside those objects there are key value pairs like these:

```
businesses: 
[{business_id: '1' , title: '1', active: '1'},{ business_id: '2' , title: '2', active: '2'}]
```

I want to output only the title of the current object.

So here is what I have done

```
{{#each businesses}}{{#each this}}{{this}}{{/each}}{{/each}}
```

so i'm iterating over an array then iterating over the current object and i want only the title, but the current code give me all values.

I tried to do instead of `{{this}} {{this.title}}` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

got it.

changed: `{{#each businesses}}{{#each this}}{{this}}{{/each}}{{/each}}`

to : `{{#each businesses}}{{this.title}}{{/each}}`

i didn't need to go over all the object properties.